See and control OpenVPN server via nodejs
I want to control (start/stop, see if running and current connections) an OpenVPN server that is already installed on the system via nodejs. I don't want to create one via nodejs.
I tried to search if a module like this already exists but I did only find ones for creating a server. Another way to get those information, except for the amount of current connections, would be by looking for a module that reads out windows services and checks if the openVPN service is running. I could also start/stop the server like that. A slight problem with that would be that I would also need to write a function that does the same for linux but thats not thaat bad.
Is there a better way to do what I want to do?
